# seo friendly url and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo

I finally found a way to remove get parameters from my urls
i had url like
**/s.com/file.php?name=somthing**

with this code i changed them to **s.com/file/somthing**

Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^file/(.*?)$ http://s.com/file.php?name=$1

so far everything is ok

in my local host when i click on a url like **s.com/file/somthing** it goes exactly to the url

but in my server it redirects to old url and shows old url

i dont want to display my old url

can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http redirects are always external => visible in the browser. Try that:

```
RewriteRule ^file/(.*?)$ /file.php?name=$1
```